# Utility meters in an AMF panel

Tags: power-supply, mains, generator, distribution-board

Without the DG, the mains goes to, say, 5 flats in my apartment through 5 utility meters.

However, with AMF, the DG is shorted to mains. Wouldn't the utility meters count DG energy too?

[image]

Comment: Hi ... can I ask what are "dg" and "amf" and "ATS105SP"?

Comment: sorry these are electrical terms, not electronics. dg = diesel generator; amf = auto mains failure

Comment: Amf is a system which detects mains failure and connects dg output to load automatically. when mains is on again, it disconnects the dg and connects mains to load

Comment: @across, please include this information in the question body. Questions should be clear without reading the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if the utility meters are after the contactors they will record the power used from the generator as well as from the mains.

Since the connections are going to 5 units each with it's own meter there's no easy way around this, but as the generator is only expected to be used on rare occasions the added charges should be negligible.

Also, the generator is not 'shorted to mains', what should happen in a power outage is the contactor from mains is opened and the one from the generator is closed, so one or the other is connected to 'LOAD', they're never actually connected together.